# Calculation during Excel SQL query

Tags: sql, excel

I would like to get some data from SQL server to Excel. I want to make a calculation at query, but I get a syntax error.

How can I make this calculation?

```
SELECT .........
      .........., 
      ((SX.AP)-(SX.US*SX.UG))/2.1 AS MARGIN
,.......... 
FROM ....
```

Comment: What you try so far ? provide some sample data

Comment: Have you tried this same query directly in SQL? Does not seem like an issue with Excel or its connection to your DB server but rather just the syntax of your query.

Comment: try to get some columns from sql but try to make calculation during query. margin = quantity*cost / currency: rest of my query works wekk but this calculation not. here is another not works ; (SX.AP-SX.US*SX.UG/2.8498) AS MARGIN

Comment: for example this works very well (SX.AP-SX.US*SX.UG) AS MARGIN but when I put divide currency not works -->(SX.AP-SX.US*SX.UG/2.8498) AS MARGIN

Answer (score 0):

finally found this works ;

(SX.AP/2.1-SX.US/2.1*SX.UG) AS MARGIN,